# Zoo Visitor Fields Displaying Tag Instead Of Member Data

Tags: ee2, zoo-visitor

I am trying to map the member fields of EE2 to the zoo visitor fields to display the user's previously registered shipping and billing details and I am using the value '`{visitor:global:shipping_phone}`' to retrieve the values, but the value of the phone field is showing the actual text '`{visitor:global:shipping_phone}`'. I am wrapping my form fields with the '`{exp:zoo_visitor:details}`' tag.

I have also mapped the two fields in the backend.

What else am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shipping_phone` is not a [ZV global variable](http://ee-zoo.com/docs/visitor/global-variables.html). If the tag doesn't exist then it will always just output as a string. If this is on the member account page then you just need to use the [member details tag pair](http://ee-zoo.com/docs/visitor/tags/member-details.html#member-details-tag-examples) with their respective fields as shown in their docs.